# Implement a drop down box with ajax and jquery ui slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-slider, dropdownbox

Im not too good at coding unfortunately but I am still trying to do my best. I recently started using the jquery ui slider with ajax to update from my DB.

My problem is that I have the slider to change one parameter but I also need a drop down box with a second parameter. I dont know how to implement the drop down box with the existing jquery slider code.

I want to use ajax so that the DB updates automatically BOTH if I drag the slider (which works) and if I change in the drop down (right now I can collect the value from the drop down but i cant make it update automatically with ajax, it only changes once i also drag the slider).

If someone could give me an example of how to write the code so that I can use both the slider and the drop down so that it updates automatically onchange that would be amazing! Thanks.

My slider works with jquery. The function I have for this (value2 is where I have collected the value from the drop down right now, but obviously I need a function for this):

```
$(function slider() {

$.ui.slider.prototype.widgetEventPrefix = 'slider';

$( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
range: "max",
min: 1,
max: 4,
step: 1,
value: 2,
stop: function( event, ui ) {
$( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );

var value1 = ui.value;
var value2 = document.getElementById("livebelopp").value

$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/slider-results.php",
        data: "loptid="+value1+"&belopp="+value2,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
        $("#content_update").html(html);
        }
    });

}

});

});
```

The drop down is simple:

```
<form>
<select style="border-radius: 5px;" id="livebelopp">
<option value="500">500 kr</option>
<option value="1000">1 000 kr</option>
<option value="2000">2 000 kr</option>
<option value="3000" selected="selected">3 000 kr</option>
<option value="4000">4 000 kr</option>
<option value="5000">5 000 kr</option>
<option value="6000">6 000 kr</option>
<option value="7000">7 000 kr</option>
<option value="8000">8 000 kr</option>
<option value="9000">9 000 kr</option>
<option value="10000">10 000 kr</option>
</select> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does it

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var sliderValue = 2;    // make sure this corresponds to the default
      $(function slider() {
        $.ui.slider.prototype.widgetEventPrefix = 'slider';
        $("#slider-range-max").slider({
          range: "max",
          min: 1,
          max: 4,
          step: 1,
          value: 2,
          stop: function( event, ui ) {
            sliderValue = ui.value;   // easiest solution; keep the value somewhere; we read this variable just before sending the data. 
            send_update();
          }
        });
      });
      // onChange of the select
      $('#livebelopp').change(function() {
        send_update();
      });
      /**
      *  We let both the onChange of the <select> and the onStop of the slider trigger this function.
      */
      function send_update() {
        var value1 = sliderValue;
        var value2 = $("#livebelopp").val();
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "slider-results.php",
          data: {loptid: value1, belopp: value2},  // object notation
          cache: false,
          success: function(html) {
            $("#content_update").html(html);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="slider-range-max"></div>
  <form>
    <select style="border-radius: 5px;" id="livebelopp">
      <option value="500">500 kr</option>
      <option value="1000">1 000 kr</option>
      <option value="2000">2 000 kr</option>
      <option value="3000" selected="selected">3 000 kr</option>
      <option value="4000">4 000 kr</option>
      <option value="5000">5 000 kr</option>
      <option value="6000">6 000 kr</option>
      <option value="7000">7 000 kr</option>
      <option value="8000">8 000 kr</option>
      <option value="9000">9 000 kr</option>
      <option value="10000">10 000 kr</option>
    </select> 
  </form>
  <hr>
  <div id="content_update"></div>
</body>
```

For debugging, I did this:

slider-results.php

```
<?php
echo 'Request: <pre>' . print_r($_GET, true) . '</pre>'; 
?>
```

Comment: Wow that worked perfectly. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out. I really appreciate it. Im gonna try to look at it and figure out what you did here so that i can learn. Thanks again.